# How to format axis labels in a Primefaces chart

Tags: java, primefaces, charts

I am looking for a way to format axis labes. Here is how my chart is shown:
[image]

I want 5000000 to be shown as 50M or 50,000,000. I couldn't find any way to perform such important action. Code is in java. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

With primefaces 5.1 just do this:

```xml
<p:chart type="line">
```

Using the new tag, and in the Java code just do this:

```java
lineCharModelFinanceiro = new LineChartModel();

lineCharModelFinanceiro.getAxes().put(AxisType.X, new CategoryAxis("Meses"));

Axis yAxis = lineCharModelFinanceiro.getAxis(AxisType.Y);

yAxis.setTickFormat("%.2f");
yAxis.setLabel("Valor R$");
yAxis.setMin(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Use your lineChart with addition tag `extender` in which you should provide java scripts for display with formatted String. i am using in my project and it working fine. xhtml code and java csripts as below.

```
<p:lineChart id="linear" value="#{xxxxxxxx}"
            legendPosition="e" title="Linear Chart" extender="overrideXAxis"
            style="height:300px" />


<script>
        function overrideXAxis() {
            this.cfg.axes = {
                yaxis : {
                    tickOptions : {
                        formatString : "%dM",
                        angle : 0
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    </script>
```

it will give you required output.

[image]

Comment: It appends a suffix 'M'. But I also need to format the value. So, Is there an API for what this.cfg.axes contains, so that I can easily take actions on values? I am new with UI design, so I also appreciate if you help.

Comment: visit link http://www.jqplot.com/index.php . it may helpful. but i don`t find out the way to show 5000000 in format 5,000,000. or you can consider 10M = 1000000 and write your logic.

Answer (score 1):

To format yaxis numbers with digit grouping, add following to your custom extender

**this.cfg.axes.xaxis.tickOptions.formatString = "%'d"**

(jqPlot uses single quote (') to format number with digit grouping)